# Facing an issue while making a production build for my angular project with backend in C#

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-material, fusioncharts

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/angular-fusioncharts/src/fusioncharts.component.d.ts.FusionChartsComponent.html(2,10):
>   : Property 'containerId' does not exist on type
>   'FusionChartsComponent

Below is the code for my node modules `fusioncharts.component.d.ts` file I have tried so many things to resolve this issue like updating npm, updating `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, npm I nyc, updating `tslint` file and so on but haven't found any solution for my problem

```
import { ElementRef, OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, KeyValueDiffers, NgZone, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FusionChartsService } from './fusioncharts.service';
import FusionChartsEvent from '../interfaces/FusionChartsEvent';
import FusionChartInstance from '../interfaces/FusionChartInstance';
declare class FusionChartsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy{
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    ngAfterViewInit(): void;
    ngDoCheck(): void;
    ngOnInit(): void;
    ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void;

    private differs;
    private zone;
    chartObj: any;
    placeholder: string;
    dataSource: any;
    type: string;
    id: string;
    width: string;
    height: string;
    renderAt: string;
    dataFormat: string;
    events: string;
    link: string;
    showDataLoadingMessage: boolean;
    showChartLoadingMessage: boolean;
    baseChartMessageFont: string;
    baseChartMessageFontSize: string;
    baseChartMessageColor: string;
    dataLoadStartMessage: string;
    dataLoadErrorMessage: string;
    dataInvalidMessage: string;
    dataEmptyMessage: string;
    typeNotSupportedMessage: string;
    loadMessage: string;
    renderErrorMessage: string;
    containerBackgroundColor: string;
    containerBackgroundOpacity: string;
    containerClassName: string;
    baseChartMessageImageHAlign: string;
    baseChartMessageImageVAlign: string;
    baseChartMessageImageAlpha: number;
    baseChartMessageImageScale: number;
    typeNotSupportedMessageImageHAlign: string;
    typeNotSupportedMessageImageVAlign: string;
    typeNotSupportedMessageImageAlpha: number;
    typeNotSupportedMessageImageScale: number;
    dataLoadErrorMessageImageHAlign: string;
    dataLoadErrorMessageImageVAlign: string;
    dataLoadErrorMessageImageAlpha: number;
    dataLoadErrorMessageImageScale: number;
    dataLoadStartMessageImageHAlign: string;
    dataLoadStartMessageImageVAlign: string;
    dataLoadStartMessageImageAlpha: number;
    dataLoadStartMessageImageScale: number;
    dataInvalidMessageImageHAlign: string;
    dataInvalidMessageImageVAlign: string;
    dataInvalidMessageImageAlpha: number;
    dataInvalidMessageImageScale: number;
    dataEmptyMessageImageHAlign: string;
    dataEmptyMessageImageVAlign: string;
    dataEmptyMessageImageAlpha: number;
    dataEmptyMessageImageScale: number;
    renderErrorMessageImageHAlign: string;
    renderErrorMessageImageVAlign: string;
}
```

Comment: If you could share more on your implementation end, it will be easier for debugging the problem, your component ts, module & html file

Answer (score 0):

"containerId" property is missing in your FusionChartsComponent ts file.
Try declaring public property for the same.
Can you please share your FusionChartsComponent.html file